# How can I use jQuery to hide or show table rows based on asp.net role?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

**How can I use jQuery to hide or show table rows based on asp.net role?**

Maybe I'm going about this in a wrong way, but I *have* attempted to search the forums, experiment on my own, and go through whole loops of trial and error. :)

This question is in regards to an asp.net page, where I have successfully managed to display the web.sitemap file as an html table, per the client's request.

Given that I have saved the user's Active Directory group in a hidden field (in this system the user must belong to one group and can only be in one group).

What I need to do now is

1. Loop through each row in the table
2. Read the "data-group" attribute held by each  element, which can be a comma-delimited string, a single value string, or "*".
3. If the user's group is found in the "data-group" attribute then change the css class accordingly.  The css class -- in this example changes the background to black or green, depending on whether the user's group is found or not.

I have attempted to this with jQuery and seem to be stuck.  I've been using jsFiddle to troubleshoot my code.  According to jsFiddle my jQuery code is valid, and yet I'm not seeing the behavior I need.

I'm willing to bet I'm going wrong in a very simple way, but I'm missing it. Can anyone see where I 'm going wrong?

I'm pasting my jQuery, CSS, and a sample HTML block in that order.  The HTML table is only a *subsample* of a much larger table. This is shown just for example purposes.

Thank you for any insight.

jQuery block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var strUser = $("#hfUserADGroup").val();
    var tblSitemap = $("#tblSitemap");
    var strGroup;

    tblSitemap.find("tr").each(function () {
        strGroup = $(this).data("roles");
        var arrGroup = strGroup.split(",");
        if (jQuery.isArray(strUser, arrGroup) == -1) {
            $(this).attr("class") = "HiddenObject";
        } else {
            $(this).attr("class") = "ShowObject";
        }
    });
});
```

CSS Block:

```
.trow1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.level1 {
    margin-left: 0em;
}

.level2 {
 margin-left: 1em;
}

.trow2 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.level3 {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

.trow3 {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

.level4 {
margin-left: 3em;
}

.trow4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #FAFAD2;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.level5 {
margin-left: 4em;
}

.HiddenObject {
background-color: black;
}

.ShowObject {
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML Block:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfUserADGroup" id="hfUserADGroup" value="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager" />
<table id="tblSitemap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border:thin solid gold;">Title</th>
            <th style="border:thin solid gold;">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="trow1" data-roles="*">
            <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level1">Homepage</span>

            </td>
            <td style="border:thin solid gold;">Descriptive sitemap for all pages available through the ROSE network.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trow2" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Clerk">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level2">Business</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;">Pages intended for use by the Business Department.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow3" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Clerk">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level3">Incident Report</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow4" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Clerk">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level4">Add/Edit Records</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;">Use this page to add or view new records.    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow4" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Clerk">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level4">View Records Before 8/14/2014</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;">This is a read-only table for historical searches.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow3" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business_Manager">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level3">Inventory</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;">Under development; not released yet.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow3" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business,ROSE\DM_RMG_Business_Manager">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level3">Marketing</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;">This view allows you to choose the campus of interest.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow2" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_CRA_Principal,ROSE\DM_CRA_Teacher,ROSE\DM_CRA_Clerk,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Director,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Specialist,ROSE\DM_RMG_SS_Clerk,ROSE\DM_RMG_SS_Manager">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level2">CRA</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow3" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_CRA_Principal,ROSE\DM_CRA_Clerk">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level3">Marketing</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow3" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_CRA_Principal,ROSE\DM_CRA_Clerk">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level3">Credit Slip Log</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow3" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_CRA_Principal,ROSE\DM_CRA_Clerk,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Director,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Specialist">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level3">Surveys</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow4" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_CRA_Principal,ROSE\DM_CRA_Clerk,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Director,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Specialist">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level4">SPED Parent Satisfaction</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow4" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_CRA_Principal,ROSE\DM_CRA_Clerk">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level4">Student Enrollment</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trow3" data-roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_CRA_Principal,ROSE\DM_CRA_Teacher,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Director,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Specialist,ROSE\DM_RMG_SS_Clerk,ROSE\DM_RMG_SS_Manager">
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"> <span class="level3">MIA Goal Tracker</span>

        </td>
        <td style="border:thin solid gold;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an updated fiddle to accomplish what I think you're looking to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/hwm5jjyu/

Your example did not make use of the strUser variable to check if the value was in the array.  I updated the code to 1) check if the role attribute exists, and then if it does check the resulting array for the value of strUser using indexOf.  Lastly you want to use the addClass jQuery method or in vanilla JS this.className = "new Class" to change the class name of the table row.  I'm not sure how you want the "*" to behave in the sample so I left it alone, in this example it will turn the row black because it does not match strUsr.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var strUser = $("#hfUserADGroup").val();
    var tblSitemap = $("#tblSitemap");
    var strGroup;

    tblSitemap.find("tr").each(function () {
        strGroup = $(this).data("roles");
        if(strGroup){
            var arrGroup = strGroup.split(",");
            if (arrGroup.indexOf(strUser) == -1) {
                $(this).addClass("HiddenObject");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("ShowObject");
            }
        }
    });
});
```